# Tezos is branched on a block XX which is too old

Tags: node, wallets

we've been seeing inconsistent errors when we broadcast to our full node. We use the latest block as our branch when broadcasting but still encounter this:

```
Operation ooAZXxx9q5f5Kn4vpCuGG8EdTADL29gYbH8sjWw6jJ2VLErJ9B5 is branched on a block BLrjupXkEqWF2r282WJTuTXw4JwekFpTA9r1mAfn34LjVbXatJt which is too old - Hash: ooAZXxx9q5f5Kn4vpCuGG8EdTADL29gYbH8sjWw6jJ2VLErJ9B5
```

We've noticed that sometimes this means that transaction will never make it on chain, but there are other instances where it does make it on chain when we see this response.

Any suggestions on how to prevent this in the first place since we don't truly know what to mark this transaction (failed or succeeded) when we see this error which is giving us inconsistencies in our transaction statuses.

Comment: It's recommended not to use the latest block (aka head candidate) hash as operation branch, because of reorgs. I guess that Tezos node does not make the difference if the branch hash is outdated (i.e. >120 levels old) or orphaned (terminal chain branch) thus the message might be misleading.

Comment: Got it @MichaelZaikin. Do you have a recommendation of how many blocks behind I should be grabbing the hash from?

Comment: People used 55 when the operation TTL was 60 because stuck operations could not be replaced without restarting the node. With Tenderbake, three blocks behind should be enough since now the block finality is two confirmations. https://mainnet.visualtez.com/chains/main/blocks/head~3

Comment: @RodrigoQuelhas so actually tried using 5 block behind chain and still got the same error. It’s not consistent when it happens either.

Comment: The three blocks behind should solve the issue with reorgs. About the operation not being included, probably you are not providing a fee high enough, and the other nodes mempool is rejecting it. (Make sure you estimate the costs and add a small threshold) https://tezostaquito.io/docs/estimate

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoQuelhas, this helped